TypeScript type with multiple objects with arbitrary keys
I'm struggling to define a TypeScript type for data in the following structure (comes from a Neptune/neo4J database). The object in the results array may have 0+ keys. The names of the keys (in this example a, m and d are arbitrary however the structure of each value object will always contain the three fields Name, Description and online are always going to be present.
{
  "results": [
    {
      "a": {
        "properties": {
          "Name": "B-01",
          "Description": "first item",
          "online": true
        }
      },
      "m": {
        "properties": {
          "Name": "A32RD",
          "Description": "another item",
          "online": false
        }
      },
      "d": {
        "properties": {
          "Name": "ANO123",
          "Description": "third item",
          "online": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Can anyone suggest how I could define this type? Alternatively are there any predefined types for Neptune / Neo4J?
Thanks

You can define this type like this:
interface Properties {
  Name: string;
  Description: string;
  online: boolean;
}

interface Result {
  [key: string]: {
    properties: Properties;
  };
}

interface ResultData {
  results: Result[];
}

